# Selected Radio button displays text input with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a group of radio boxes where you can select your amount. The last option is Other. I'd like that option to show an Amount field once it's checked. This is built using jquery mobile.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rmlumley/jafmC/)

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<legend>Select Amount</legend>
<input type="radio" name="amount" id="50" value="50" checked="checked"/>
<label for="50">$50</label>

<input type="radio" name="amount" id="100" value="100"/>
<label for="100">$100</label>

<input type="radio" name="amount" id="250" value="250"/>
<label for="250">$250</label>

<input type="radio" name="amount" id="500" value="500"/>
<label for="500">$500</label>

<input type="radio" name="amount" id="1000" value="1000"/>
<label for="1000">$1000</label>

<input type="radio" name="amount" id="other" value="other"/>
<label for="other">Other</label>
    <div id="enter_amount">
        <label for="other_amount">Enter Amount:</label>
        <input type="text" name="other_amount" id="other_amount" value="" data-theme="d"  />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

What do I need to write for this to work? I'm currently trying the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enter_amount").css("display","none");
        $("#other").click(function(){
        if ($('#other:checked')) {
            $("#enter_amount").slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect
        } else {
            $("#enter_amount").slideUp("slow");  //Slide Up Effect
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working outside of simply hiding the input box on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .change instead of .click. Also i modified your code to account for some other scenarios. 
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jafmC/9/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#enter_amount').hide(); 
    $('fieldset :radio').change(function(){
       if( this.id === 'other' )
           $('#enter_amount').slideDown('slow'); 
        else if( $('#enter_amount').is(':visible') )
           $('#enter_amount').slideUp('slow');               
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These are radio buttons so when another radio button is checked then other will be unchecked by default.  Therefore you should bind to all inputs with the name 'amount'.  Also the use of the [jQuery.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) would be a better approach to seeing if the checkbox is checked. Also use the [jQuery.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)  event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enter_amount").css("display","none");
    $('input[name="amount"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is('#other')) {
            $("#enter_amount").slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect
        } else {
            $("#enter_amount").slideUp("slow");  //Slide Up Effect
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jafmC/13/

Answer (score 0):

you have to change it to:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#enter_amount").slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect
        } else {
            $("#enter_amount").slideUp("slow");  //Slide Up Effect
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enter_amount").css("display","none");
        $("#other").click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#enter_amount").slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect
        } else {
            $("#enter_amount").slideUp("slow");  //Slide Up Effect
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not really interacting with the radio buttons themselves any more (use the 'inspect element' feature in Firebug, Web Inspector or Dragonfly to see), but instead the elements supplied by jQuery Mobile (or jQuery UI), you have to amend your selectors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#enter_amount").css("display", "none");
    $(".ui-radio").click(function() {
        if ($(this).has('#other') && $(this).has('.ui-icon-radio-on')){
            $('#enter_amount').slideDown(500); // works
        }
        else {
            $('#enter_amount').slideUp(500); // doesn't yet work
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jafmC/2/).

---

**Edited** (following ***quite*** some irritation, I must confess) to add an improved (ie 'functioning') `if` / `else` check:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#enter_amount").css("display", "none");
    $(".ui-radio").click(function() {
        if ($(this).find('#other').length) {
            $('#enter_amount').slideDown(500);
        }
        else {
            $('#enter_amount').slideUp(500);
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jafmC/21/).

Comment: This mostly works, but the #enter_amount field shows up whenever any of the radio buttons are checked.

Comment: Yeah; I'm trying to work that one out myself...I can't see why it's always true. This is one of the few times I've ever (literally) sworn at the computer asking "how the ____ can it be always _______ true..!?" Ugh.

Comment: I think @Interstellar_Coder nailed it above.

Comment: Try the edits (post-`hr`). It *seems* to work reliably now...sigh.

Comment: David, it's the `$(this).has(other)` That returns an empty array and it evaluates to true. Try `$(this).has(other).length`

Comment: Ah, I hadn't refreshed the page, or seen his/her approach until now; but that way works as well, yep. @Interstellar_Coder: yeah; I worked it out eventually (hence my change to using `.length`), but it frustrated me originally, because I expected it to function much as `is()`, and return a Boolean true(y)/false(y) value. Sigh.

Comment: Got me thinking for a bit too, don't blame you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enter_amount").hide();

    $("input[name='amount']").change(function(){

        if($(":checked").val() == "other"){
            $("#enter_amount").slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect
        } else {
            $("#enter_amount").slideUp("slow");  //Slide Up Effect
        }
    });
});
```

you could try this